# Order pair of ints inserted by input

Tags: c

Im getting input from user and then order a order of pairs if its possible

**Case 1 -** 4 pairs input `[1,2][2,3][3,4][4,5]` This a possible input so i should order this and show `1,2,3,4,5`

**Case 2 -**4 pairs input `[1,2][2,3][3,2][4,5]` this is inculent so just show a message that doesnt make sense

Im trying doing this by using a adjacency matrix but now im stuck!

I create a adjacency matrix marking user input

**Case 1 Matrix would be:**

[image]

Comment: Why not store your input in a 2D array where each row has two elements (your pairs) and then you can just loop through the array to check and provide your output? If you don't know how may pairs, then dynamically allocate for a *pointer-to-array-of* `int[2]`, e.g. `int (*pairs)[2];`?

Comment: Thats what im trying to do but using adjacency because if i have my both index+1 will give me the pair where equal to 1

Comment: Okay, hold on and I'll work up an example. Do the pairs in each row have to be separate by one as shown, e.g. `arr[row][0] == 1 && arr[0][1] == 2` -- good pair? And does the next row have to have a pair one-greater-than the last row?

Comment: Where im stuck at is because i dont know what to do now with the matrix to give the outputs that i want.

Comment: Couple of thoughts,`matrixAdj[pair1-1][pair2-1]=1;` there is no validation of `pair1` or `pair2`. If either or `0` or greater than `numberdoc`, then *Undefined Behavior* results. Also, you must validate the return of `scanf()` every time to determine whether a *matching failure* occurs before the values are used. If a *matching failure* occurs, character extraction from `stdin` ceases leaving the offending character in the input buffer unread. That is why reading a line-at-a-time and then using `sscanf()` is the better approach. The rest of your implementation is provided below.

Comment: But in your implementation you dont show the numbers in order in the end(1) or print a message saying that is contradictory(2) thats what im trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a 2D array to collect your pairs like:

```
#define MAXPAIRS 20     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC   1024
...
    char line[MAXC];                    /* buffer to hold each line of input */
    int pairs[MAXPAIRS][2] = {{0}},     /* 2D array to hold pairs */
        npairs = 0;                     /* number of pairs entered */
```

You can read each pair into your 2D array as follows:

```
    while (npairs < MAXPAIRS) {                     /* loop while array not full */
        printf ("enter pair [%2d] : ", npairs);     /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {           /* read/validate line */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            break;
        }
        else if (*line == '\n')                     /* end input on ENTER alone */
            break;
        /* parse integers from line into pair */
        if (sscanf (line, "%d %d", &pairs[npairs][0], &pairs[npairs][1]) != 2) {
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        npairs++;       /* increment counter */
    }
```

(**note:** if you want your prompt to ask for `"pair[1]... pair[2] ..."` instead of `"pair[0]... pair[1]..."`, you can use `printf ("enter pair [%2d] : ", npairs + 1);` adding `1` to the `npairs` value.)

Which simply collects pairs from the user until the array is full, or the user signals done entering input by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone on the line after the last input.

With your pairs stored, you can loop over the array validating that the array is incluent, between rows (if required) and between pair values, creating your matrix as you go:

```
    int matrix[npairs+1][npairs+1];             /* using a VLA */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < npairs + 1; i++) {      /* loop over pairs + 1 */
        /* 2nd row on, check value is 1-greater than previous row */
        if (i && i < npairs && pairs[i][0] - pairs[i-1][0] != 1) {
            fputs ("  error: not incluent - between rows.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        /* check that pair values are adjacent, increasing */
        if (i < npairs && pairs[i][1] - pairs[i][0] != 1) {
            fputs ("  error not incluent - between pair values.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < npairs + 1; j++)    /* fill row in matrix */
            matrix[i][j] = i < npairs && j == i + 1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

If you have made it this far, you matrix is filled and your pairs incluent and you simply need to output the matrix, e.g.

```
    puts ("\nmatrix:");                         /* output matrix */
    print_matrix (npairs+1, npairs+1, matrix);
```

Putting it altogether along with the `print_matrix()` function, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXPAIRS 20     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXC   1024

/* simple print matrix function */
void print_matrix (int rows, int cols, int (*arr)[cols])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf (j ? " %d" : "%d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    char line[MAXC];                    /* buffer to hold each line of input */
    int pairs[MAXPAIRS][2] = {{0}},     /* 2D array to hold pairs */
        npairs = 0;                     /* number of pairs entered */
    
    while (npairs < MAXPAIRS) {                     /* loop while array not full */
        printf ("enter pair [%2d] : ", npairs);     /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (line, MAXC, stdin)) {           /* read/validate line */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");
            break;
        }
        else if (*line == '\n')                     /* end input on ENTER alone */
            break;
        /* parse integers from line into pair */
        if (sscanf (line, "%d %d", &pairs[npairs][0], &pairs[npairs][1]) != 2) {
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        npairs++;       /* increment counter */
    }
    
    int matrix[npairs+1][npairs+1];             /* using a VLA */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < npairs + 1; i++) {      /* loop over pairs + 1 */
        /* 2nd row on, check value is 1-greater than previous row */
        if (i && i < npairs && pairs[i][0] - pairs[i-1][0] != 1) {
            fputs ("  error: not incluent - between rows.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        /* check that pair values are adjacent, increasing */
        if (i < npairs && pairs[i][1] - pairs[i][0] != 1) {
            fputs ("  error not incluent - between pair values.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < npairs + 1; j++)    /* fill row in matrix */
            matrix[i][j] = i < npairs && j == i + 1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    
    puts ("\nmatrix:");                         /* output matrix */
    print_matrix (npairs+1, npairs+1, matrix);
}
```

(**note:** the use of a *ternary* in several places above which has the form `test ? if_true : if_false` (a shorthand `if (test) ... else ...`) It can be used virtually anywhere, function parameters, etc.., anywhere a choice is needed.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/incluentpairs
enter pair [ 0] : 1 2
enter pair [ 1] : 2 3
enter pair [ 2] : 3 4
enter pair [ 3] : 4 5
enter pair [ 4] :

matrix:
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

**Edit Per-Comment**

To output the message on error you can do:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < npairs + 1; i++) {      /* loop over pairs + 1 */
        /* 2nd row on, check value is 1-greater than previous row */
        if (i && i < npairs && pairs[i][0] - pairs[i-1][0] != 1) {
            fputs ("  error: not incluent - between rows.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        /* check that pair values are adjacent, increasing */
        if (i < npairs && pairs[i][1] - pairs[i][0] != 1) {
            if (i) {
                char msg[64];
                sprintf (msg, "contradictory %d->%d %d->%d\n", 
                        pairs[i-1][0], pairs[i-1][1], pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]);
                fputs (msg, stderr);
            }
            else
                fputs ("  error not incluent - between pair values.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < npairs + 1; j++)    /* fill row in matrix */
            matrix[i][j] = i < npairs && j == i + 1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/incluentpairs
enter pair [ 0] : 1 2
enter pair [ 1] : 2 3
enter pair [ 2] : 3 2
enter pair [ 3] : 4 5
enter pair [ 4] :
contradictory 2->3 3->2
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions (just leave a comment below).

Comment: I was already on this step at my program! Now i want to check my matrix and see if i can order the numbers in case 1 if i can just output ordered without reps 1,2,3,4,5 and in case 2 show message saying that is contradictory 2->3 3->2 is contradictory example!

Comment: Well, sure, you already have the checks in place to catch that (the second `if`), so just use `char msg[32]; sprintf (msg, "contradictory %d->%d %d->%d", pairs[i-1][0], pairs[i-1][1], paris[i][0], pairs[i][1]); puts (msg);`. When you fail to post code, it is impossible to tell what step you are stuck on. Your original question said `"so just show a message that doesnt make sense"` which doesn't appear to put any focus on what  you are describing now.